# Type of analysis for water

Tags: analytical-chemistry

What other analysis suitable for water as general? Right now, I have turbidity, pH, Total Soluble Solid and color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Hardness
- **TC** Total Carbon

  - **TIC** Total Inorganic Carbon
  - **TOC** Total Organic Carbon
  - **VOC** Volatile Organic Carbon
- **COD** Chemical Oxygen Demand
- **BOD** Biochemical Oxygen Demand

Comment: @anonymous My pleasure. If the anwer was really helpful, please consider to [accept](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Comment: Also trace metal concentrations, disinfectant byproducts, fluoride, nitrite, nitrate.  I'm kind of presuming drinking water with these though.

Comment: @airhuff Absolutely! I only listed  some parameters for which wikipedia pages with further explanation exist.